# Facebook PHP SDK v4 manage_pages permission for non developer account

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

We are trying to create an app to pull in facebook reviews which requires the manage_page permission. This is not an app which we would like to submit for review as we are only using this for our clients.

We are currently able to get the access token for all pages when logging in as the administration developers.facebook.com account using the following code below which gives us the data array with all access_tokens as expected.

However the problem we have is when we try to login with the clients facebook account the array is empty.

So we tried to add them as an admin for the app which is not ideal as they are not developers so would not be happy with this approach.

I believe this is not working due to manage_page permission.
Does anyone know a way around this without having to submit the app for review?

```
  $app_id     = '1234567890';
  $app_secret = 'ABCDEFGHIJKM';
  $facebook = FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id, $app_secret);
  $session  = FacebookSession::newAppSession();

  $callback_url = 'http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

  $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($callback_url, $app_id, $app_secret);

  try {
      $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
  } catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo 'FacebookSDKException Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      $session = null;
  } catch(\Exception $ex) {
      echo 'Exception Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }

  print "<pre>"; print_r($session); print "</pre>";

  if ($session) {
    // User logged in, get the AccessToken entity.
    $accessToken = $session->getAccessToken();
    // Exchange the short-lived token for a long-lived token.
    $longLivedAccessToken = $accessToken->extend();
    // Make calls to Graph with the long-lived token.
  } else {
    echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Login with Facebook</a>';
  }

  FacebookSession::enableAppSecretProof(false);

  try {
      $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/accounts?fields=name,access_token,perms');
      $pageList = $request->execute()
          ->getGraphObject()
          ->asArray();
  } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
      echo 'FacebookRequestException Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  } catch(\Exception $ex) {
      echo 'Exception Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  }

  print "<pre>"; print_r($pageList); print "</pre>";
```

Comment: There is no way around it. Permission review is there for a reason.

Comment: It seems a little extreme as we just want to display reviews not post anything just view them.

Comment: If you want to ask for permission from people that doesn't have a role on the app then you need to get the permission approved

Comment: Ok so after we go through the review process how can we use the same app across different sites?

Comment: The review process makes it possible to ask users that doesn't have a role on the app. It doesn't do anything else